# Get values from MultiValueMap

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I use this code to get values from an HTTP request:

```
@PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE, value = "/v1/notification")
  public ResponseEntity<String> handleNotifications(@RequestBody MultiValueMap<String, Object> keyValuePairs) {

    LOGGER.debug("handleFormMessage");
    LOGGER.debug("keyValuePairs: {}", keyValuePairs);

    String unique_id = String.valueOf(keyValuePairs.get("unique_id"));

    System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!! ! unique_id " + unique_id);
}
```

But I get this value: `!!!!!!!!!!!!!! ! unique_id [24q376c3ts2kh3o3220rry322dfe2k7y]`.

Is there a way to remove `[]` from the String without the classical `String result = str.substring(0, index) + str.substring(index+1);`?

Is there a way to get the values?

I use this to post the values:

[image]

Comment: Are you providing `unique_id` as a list in your call to this endpoint?

Comment: No, I send it as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Answer (score 5):

If you always provide only **one value** for `unique_id`, you can, instead of `get`, use [`getFirst`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/MultiValueMap.html#getFirst-K-) which

> Returns the first value for the given key

Your code would go like this:

```
String unique_id = String.valueOf(keyValuePairs.getFirst("unique_id"));
```

Remember, this method actually returns the first value for the specified key, or `null` if none is found.

---

In case you send **more than one value** you need to treat them as a [Collection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html). For example:

```
Collection<String> unique_ids = keyValuePairs.get("unique_id");
```

After that you can do with all the ids as you wish, for example, print them:

```
unique_ids.stream().forEach(System.out:println);
```

Comment: In case I send 2 times unique_id keys? What I can do to prevent code issue?

Answer (score 2):

MultivaluedMap is an interface inheriting Map, and how you can see the object you get is a list

```
public interface MultivaluedMap<K,V> extends Map<K,List<V>>
```

Then you can do this and get the first element of the list:

```
String unique_id = String.valueOf(keyValuePairs.getFirst("unique_id"));
```